# Ethernet Not Working In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in dual boot system!

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a dual boot system with windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 . Ethernet is working perfectly fine in windows 10 but on the contrary Ubuntu shows "Cable unplugged" . I have been surfing the web for about 3 days now but have not got any solution to my problem though I tried a lot of things. Please Help Me out!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html

(these are just additional characters to satisfy the client)

Comment: I have a problem of wired connection not wireless